# Rewrite condition to check mobile user agent from smart phones

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite

I am writing rewrite condition to check user agent.

```
1. The request should be from Mobile and
2. The request should not be from iphone/Black Berry/Android Device/ Windows Phone
```

I got some thing like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mobile [AND]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"android|blackberry|IOS|windows phone" [NC]
```

Can some one correct this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|Windows Phone).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /go_to_mobile_or_403/$1 [L]
```

source:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html#HTTP_USER_AGENT

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to add not condition and checking mobile also. Can you also include that.

Comment: If You want to detect feature phones, there is no easy and precise way to do that. There is WURFL but it is quite "heavy". Try to get some inspiration from: http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/tablet-and-mobile-device-detection-php