# Multiple user agent strings in 1 htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, setenvif

I want to include multiple agent strings in 1 htaccess (or multiple if that is needed a.k.a each file for new agent string) file and I am not sure if that is possible

This is my current code

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "PRIVATESTRING" good_bot
<FilesMatch ".exe">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from env=good_bot
</FilesMatch>
```

`PRIVATESTRING` is because I am using an app that sends a custom user agent string as user logs in to download an item from my website

EDIT:
Answer: Repeat first line multiple time for each string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite condition to check mobile user agent from smart phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981991/rewrite-condition-to-check-mobile-user-agent-from-smart-phones)

Comment: I've removed the PHP and HTML tags since they don't look relevant at all. If I'm missing something please feel free to edit the question and explain yourself.

Comment: You can simply repeat the first line multiple times …